# Wht is the right word order?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

大家好！ I need these questions for one discussion in Chinese classes.

Could you please check, if I use the right word order in these questions? Thank you! :)

他和你用哪种语言谈话？

学习语言的时候有什么困难？

一个孩子每天多长时间应该练习语言？

一个儿童可以说几种语言？

你哪种语言应该学习？

你的父母会什么语言?

你未来想不想学习一种新的语言？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *他和你用哪种语言谈话？*

"他和你用哪种语言**交谈**？"

'交谈' is better than '谈话' because '交谈' means 'talk to each others; while '谈话' mainly means 'speak' or 'talk'.

You can speak or talk by yourself, but you cannot having a conversation on your own.

> *学习语言的时候有什么困难？*

No problem above

> *一个孩子每天多长时间应该练习语言？*

"一个孩子每天应该**花**多长时间练习语言?"

Better add an verb '花'(spend) here

> *一个儿童可以说几种语言？*

No problem above

> 你哪种语言应该学习？

You are placing the [**object**] directly after the [**subject** ]

- [**你**][**哪种语言**]

It is better to place the verb '**学习**'directly after the subject '**你**'

- "哪种语言**你**应该**学习**?"
- "**你**应该**学习**哪种语言?"

> *你的父母会什么语言?*

No problem here

> *你未来想不想学习一种新的语言？*

你**将来**想不想学习一种新的语言？

Should replace '未来' with '将来' for the meaning of: "in the future" because '未来' itself is a noun or an adjective for 'future'